# JBoss multiple authentication

Tags: authentication, jboss

Hello everyone,
            I need to get authenticated in my JBoss AS 7 by using different ways. The app is using form-based authentication, I need to implement another way to do it but without login page, maybe by using token, certification, etc... I do not know how to do it, but the authentication needs to be performed without login.

Is there a way in Jboss?

Thanks,

Luis.

Answer (score 0):

hi what are the security requirements for this other login method? you could use a certificate based authentication. all the different login method are listed here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Authentication+Modules

If you need to create your own Login module you can follow examples such as this here https://github.com/radcortez/wildfly-custom-login-module:

```
public class CustomLoginModule extends UsersRolesLoginModule {
  private CustomPrincipal principal;

  @Override
  public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    boolean login = super.login();
    if (login) {
        principal = new CustomPrincipal(getUsername(), "An user description!");
    }
    return login;
  }

  @Override
  protected Principal getIdentity() {
    return principal != null ? principal : super.getIdentity();
  }
}

public class CustomPrincipal extends SimplePrincipal {
  private String description;

  public CustomPrincipal(String name, String description) {
    super(name);
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Basically use the classes from org.jboss.security

does that help?
cheers
oliver

Comment: Thanks for replying. In regards to the first option, those modules can be used by maintaining the current form-based auth I'm using for, is this correct? I mean, without affecting the current setting. In the second option, I realized that it uses servlet spec 3.0 and I'm using servlet spec 2.5 which means that I do not have login method available to perform the login programmatically as it is shown there.

Comment: yes the modules can be used in combination with your current form-based auth by using the correct (required or sufficient) options. I do not think a difference of servlet spec would make a difference.

Comment: Servlet spec 3.0 has the login method to perform the authentication programmatically, but servlet spec 2.5 does not have this method. I did not find a way to perform the login programmatically with servlet spec 2.5

Comment: update the answer with some code sample and github link from the same author